# Lagrange Multipliers when function increases and decreases within the constraint

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have recently learned about the method of Lagrange multipliers in calc 3 and I understand it for the simple cases presented in lecture such as
 [this one, where the constraint g is a circle and the objective f has roughly parallel level curves that are monotonically increasing as we move to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5GM6.png)

However, what if I were to change the objective function f such that the w = 12 level curve was instead the w = 20 level curve? Now the local max of f on the constraint circle would occur on a level curve that cuts through the constraint circle, rather than one tangent to it. It was my understanding that there would always be tangency with the level curve and constraint at the local max/min on the constraint. Does the Lagrange multipliers method still work in this case? If not, why not (what condition have I violated)?

Comment: Keep in mind that the function is presumably continuous, so moving one level curve will move the others as well.

Comment: a simple example would be f(x, y) = -x^2 + 5, g(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 - 4. The local max on the constraint circle would cut through it?

Comment: In the unusual case where a level curve consists of critical points, then the extremum can occur at intersections with that curve rather than points of tangency to it.

Comment: ah interesting, and it seems like these will still be found by setting the gradients equal (up to scalar multiplication) right?

Comment: Yes. In this case, the multiplier will be zero.